# indexOf() - List - Android - Doesn't work like it should

Tags: java, android, android-studio, indexof

I want to use indexOf(), but it doesn't work correctly.

```
 List<String> datume = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < datumes.length(); i++){
            datume.add(datumes.getJSONObject(i).getString("Datum"));
        }
        java.util.Collections.sort(datume);
```

It looks like this:

```
[1468281600, 1468195200, 1468022400, 1467936000, 1467849600, 1467763200, 1467676800, 1467590400, 1468368000, 1468454400, 1468540800]
```

But everytime it only returns 0, when I search for this:

```
1467590400
```

with...

```
pos = datume.indexOf(preferences.getString("auswahldatum", "n"));
```

(Preferences work correctly)

Comment: Try to `trim` the dates both before adding them to the list and when using index of. `(preferences.getString("auswahldatum", "n").trim())` Might be some additional spaces that are causing it to fail finding the index.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not help :(

Comment: @Vucko, that could be, but wouldn't he get a -1 in that case? 0 indicates the match was found on the first element, and assuming the examples are correct, that is completely wrong....

Comment: @Tyler yes, you're right. But this is expected Johannes. Look at the number you're looking for! It's the least of all the other, hence after sort it is in the 0th position (lists start at 0, I think you know that).

Comment: @Vucko derp... You're right. I tried to check that the example list was sorted as the code indicated, but I apparently can't read. Nice catch!

Comment: Me neither, I didn't spot it the first time, but after you pointed out that it returning 0 would result in it being the first element (which I hadn't quite thought of the first time), I then realized it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually working as it should. You're sorting the `ArrayList`, and value `1467590400`, being the smallest of them all, takes the first position (**with the index of 0**) in the new sorted List.

Comment: In short, the list you have in your question isn't sorted appropriately.

Comment: Basically. But I think he's showing the list before sorting.